# Is it possible to use different forms and create one row of information in a table?

Tags: mysqli

I have been searching for a way to combine two or more rows of one table in a database into one row.

I am currently creating multiple web-based forms that connect to one table in my database.  Is there any way to write some mysql and php code that will take separate form submissions and put them into one row of the database instead of multiple rows?

Here is an example of what is going into the database:

**This is all in one table with three rows.**
Form_ID represents the three different forms that I used to insert the data into the table.

```
      Form_ID  | Lot_ID|  F_Name | L_Name |    Date     |  Age
    ------------------------------------------------------------
      1        |   1   |  John   | Evans  |   *NULL*    | *NULL*
    -------------------------------------------------------------
      2        |*NULL* | *NULL*  | *NULL* |  2017-07-06 | *NULL*
    -------------------------------------------------------------
      3        |*NULL* | *NULL*  | *NULL* |  *NULL*     |  22
```

This is an example of three separate forms going into one table.  Every time the submit button is hit the data just inserts down to the next row of information.

I need some sort of join or update once the submit button is hit to replace the preceding NULL values.

Here is what I want to do after the submit button is hit:

**I want it to be combined all into one row but still in one table**
Form_ID is still the three separate forms but only in one row now.

```
     Form_ID  |Lot_ID |  F_Name | L_Name |    Date     |  Age
    ----------------------------------------------------------
        1     |   1   |  John   | Evans  |  2017-07-06 |  22
```

My goal is once a one form has been submitted I want the next, different form submission to replace the NULL values in the row above it and so on to create a single row of information.

Comment: Why are your tables set up in this way? You need some key ID that is the same between the different tables to combine them in a meaningful way.

Comment: I am only using one table.  The forms that I am using all connect to one table and I just want to know if it is possible to connect three rows in one table and to make one.

Comment: Why would you not just put all of the details in the same row?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this issue.  I used UPDATE *tablename* SET *columname* = *newColumnName* WHERE *Form_ID* = *newID*
So this way when I want to update rows that have blanks spaces I have it finding the matching ID's